# Vscode-ROS not attaching

Tags: visual-studio-code, ros

When trying to debug Python nodes, I can't get Vscode-ROS to attach to a running node.

I did what is suggested here:
https://github.com/ms-iot/vscode-ros/blob/master/doc/debug-support.md

- Start roscore in one terminal
- Start my node in another terminal via `rosrun beginner_tutorials talker.py` (just the publisher from this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingPublisherSubscriber)
- Select a break point in the file I want to debug
- Create a simple launch configuration in VSCode and run it

Then, nothing more happens. I've also set the `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` flag when building with catkin_make, but I assume that's just for C++?

Answer (score 1):

While you can use the ROS: attach command from the command pallet (ctrl-shift-p), "F5" debugging in VSCode ROS extension is designed to work with ROS launch files.

Here's a video on how to work with VSCode ROS extension and Python - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6ABRdL0ckg&list=PL2dJBq8ig-vihvDVw-D5zAYOArTMIX0FA&index=6.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link, the way it's proposed there does indeed work (using the launch file). I'm quite confused then - isn't what I was trying to do exactly what is shown in the video on GitHub? Also, I'm really sure attaching to any running node works with a node written in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, so I was forced to use a "launch" request.

```
    {
        "name": "ROS: some_node",
        "type": "ros",
        "request": "launch",
        "target": "/path/to/launch/file"
    },
```

I know this is not convenient, but if you can write your nodes in a way that can be started and stopped at any moment, you should be OK with this approach.

On the other hand, attaching the C++ node is working fine.